# What is this end portal thingy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

I was playing Equivalent Skies modpack for a while until this strange thing appeared in my base. I can't destroy it and I don't know what it is. It just destroyed a part of my ME system.
I hope someone knows more about this and which mod it is from.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a [**Flux Rift**](https://ftb.gamepedia.com/Flux_Rift), and part of the [Thaumcraft mod](https://ftb.gamepedia.com/Thaumcraft_6):

> The Flux Rift is an immobile entity added by Thaumcraft 6. It spawns
>   when Flux in the local chunk's aura exceeds 75% of the chunk's Vis
>   cap. Flux Rifts are a source of Void Seeds, Primordial Pearls, and
>   Taint.

Be sure to move away from it, because

> Every 30 seconds, the rift will drain some Flux from the aura to
>   slightly increase in size. If the rift would extend into a block, it
>   will break that block, unless it is unbreakable. Fully stable rifts
>   cannot drain Flux to grow.